# How to Call Retrofit @DELETE method using raw json object in retrofit?

Tags: android, json, http, retrofit, retrofit2

I try to delete method of Retrofit with raw json object use to delete my list item . I once use POST method with raw method it sucess full but i need  same as @DELETE method. here post method code :

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@POST("api/tracking/post")
Call<MyResponse> getUser(@Body JsonObject jsonBody);
```

I need this type of DELETE method with raw object with this type of url

> api/tracking/delete/{user_id}

and i try with

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@DELETE("api/tracking/delete/{user_id}")
Call<MyResponse> getUser(@Body JsonObject jsonBody);
```

i put my json

```
{
"store_id":"oddeve78",
"user_id":1,
"api_token":"nzBxRT9lr2T0WDnd1DAA8Z6uXZRJQt3OyNkP6rfqCl8kEvNeyM7KoHvkqHU0}
```

Comment: Problem is that you're not passing `Path` parameter from method parameters. Add variable `@Path("user_id) String/int userId` in your `getUser` method of `@DELETE` annotation.

Comment: But i don't Need @Path params i using raw json obj. And Can i add raw and Params in same API?

Comment: With `api/tracking/delete/{user_id}`, you Are actually using `Path`.

Comment: Yes, you can. Also note: when you declare API path like this `@DELETE("api/tracking/delete/{user_id}")` you'll need to provide that user_id from Path param in from your method parameter.

Comment: I am not using it but i need this type of URL @Mahdi-Malv

Comment: You can make a function to take the json and sets the path

Comment: Can you provide example @Mahdi-Malv?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to wrap things up for you. If you really want to pass the JsonObject.

```
public Call<MyResponse> getUserByUserId(JSONObject json) {
   String userId = json.get("user_id");
   if (userId == null) return null;
   return getUser(userId);
}
```

And your call:

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@DELETE("api/tracking/delete/{user_id}")
Call<MyResponse> getUser(@Path("user_id) String userId);
```